# Create a function that return sunday dates

Tags: date, vb6

Hi guys im using vb6 i want to create a function that will return only sundays date but i will pass a date ranged example below.

```
fnWorkSunday(#09/02/2013#, #09/16/2013#)
```

The result must be: `#09/08/2013#` and `#09/15/2013#`

Comment: [What have you tried already?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: accepting a useful answer will encourage others to help you in future. You can accept the answer by clicking the tick mark below the up/down vote of the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub listSundaysBetween(startDate As Date, endDate As Date)

    Dim nextSunday As Date

    nextSunday = startDate - Weekday(startDate) + 1

    If nextSunday < startDate Then nextSunday = nextSunday + 7

    While nextSunday < endDate
        Debug.Print nextSunday
        nextSunday = nextSunday + 7
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would create an array to hold the return dated.

```
Dim dateArray() as Date
```

then loop through your date range:

```
While startDate <= endDate

    If Weekday(startDate) = 1 Then
    'or If WeekdayName(startDate) = "Sunday" Then
    '1 = vbSunday, 2 = vbMonday...

        ReDim Preserve dateArray(UBound(dateArray) + 1)
        'Resize the array to accommodate the new date
        'don't forget to preserve or all the data in the array will be lost

        dateArray(UBound(dateArray)) = startDate
    End If

    DateAdd("d",1,startDate)    'increment the startDate
WEnd
```

then return the dataArray.